# Protractor - How do I pass a string value from a previous function to an async script?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, protractor

The issue I'm having is that I have a dynamic API call whose url changes everytime.  So In order to get the proper URL I have to get the text on the page and parse it so it only the first part of the text, then concatenate that to the first part of the URL.  When I try to pass the string to the async script it keeps coming up as undefined.  How can I get the string into the async script?

Specifically get the string to this line of code:
    xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true);

```
var ID = element(by.css(".sometext")).getText().then(function(getFirstPartOfText) {
        //console.log(ID);
        var thing = getFirstPartOfText
        var thing2 = getFirstPartOfText.toString().split(" ");
        var thing3 = thing2[0];
        var API = "https://someAPIcall/read/";
        APIcall = API + thing3;
        return APIcall;
    }).then(function(APIcall){
        console.log(APIcall);
        browser.executeAsyncScript(function(ApiCall) {
            var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    callback(xhr.responseText);
                }
            };
            xhr.send('');
        }).then(function(str) {
            console.log(str);
            //var whatINeed = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an extra parameter mentioned [here](http://blog.ng-book.com/executing-async-javascript-in-protractor/)

> The first argument is a function which will be called
>   The second+ arguments will be passed as arguments to the function in the first argument.

```
var ID = element(by.css(".sometext")).getText().then(function(getFirstPartOfText) {
    //console.log(ID);
    var thing = getFirstPartOfText
    var thing2 = getFirstPartOfText.toString().split(" ");
    var thing3 = thing2[0];
    var API = "https://someAPIcall/read/";
    APIcall = API + thing3;
    return APIcall;
}).then(function(APIcall){
    console.log(APIcall);
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(ApiCall) {
        var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send('');
    }, APIcall).then(function(str) {
        console.log(str);
        //var whatINeed = JSON.parse(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ID = element(by.css(".sometext")).getText().then(function(getFirstPartOfText) {
    // this is synchronous, so there's no need to chain it using .then()
    var thing = getFirstPartOfText
    var thing2 = getFirstPartOfText.toString().split(" ");
    var thing3 = thing2[0];
    var API = "https://someAPIcall/read/";
    APIcall = API + thing3;
    return APIcall;
});

call_something(ID); // ID should be set at this point.

function call_something (APIcall) {
    console.log(APIcall);
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(ApiCall) {
        var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                callback(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send('');
    }).then(function(str) {
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this returns the html to a page not found instead of a the JSON.  If I send it a direct link for the API it returns JSON.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @QAguy what does the console spit out after `console.log(str);`? What were you expecting? What do you need to pass to `call_something()` to get the intended results?

Comment: I get <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> followed by a bunch more html.

Comment: @QAguy "If I send it a direct link for the API it returns JSON" What do you mean by this? If you would kindly post an example where you get the intended results, I'll be able to better help.

Comment: So what is happening is that after an account gets created it gets an ID.  So everytime it outputs a call it's https://someAPIcall/read/123, then when the next account gets created it would be https://someAPIcall/read/124 etc.  on the line where xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true); is if you put the direct link for some older account it returns the proper json, I'm trying to dynamically send the proper url with the ID that gets generated at creation.  Since it returns JSON when you input a direct link, I think the issue is with passing in APIcall to the async funtion.

Comment: What gets logged by `console.log(APIcall);`, and what is a full link that it works with when you hard code the link?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things going on here, first of all the `callback` in `call_something` is not required, you are still within webdriver's promise manager. So all you need to do is return the data for the next call chain. Also quote in `xhr.send('');` inside the method are not required. All you need to do is call `send()` and `JSON parse` the response and return, the next `then` block should have the JSON result. If you are getting pure HTML, then make sure the URL is correct.

```
function call_something (APIcall) {
    console.log(APIcall);
    browser.executeAsyncScript(function(ApiCall) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", APIcall, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }).then(function(str) {
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```